# I make a counter using HitCount and get an error in import transactions django.db

Tags: python, html, django

I was told that the problem is in the decorator, as I add a simple decorator in CBV https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvPh3.png)

models.py

```
   class PageHit(models.Model):
        url = models.CharField(unique=True)
        count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

decorators.py

```
from functools import wraps
from django.db.models import F
from django.db import transaction

from .models import PageHit


def counted(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic:
            counter, created = PageHit.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
            counter.count = F('count') + 1
            counter.save()
        return f(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorator
```

views.py

```
from .decorators import counted

@counted
def post_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'news/post_detail.html', {'post': article})
```

templatetags/counter.py

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(ctx, page_url=None):
    counter = (PageHit.objects
                      .filter(url=(ctx['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url))
                      .first())
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```

news/post_list.html

```
{% load counter %}

{% for article in object_list  %}
    <h3>{% page_hits article.get_absolute_url %}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

news/post_detail.html

```
{% load counter %}

<span>{% page_hits %}</span>
```

Comment: The error is in your ArticleDetail view in news/views.py. Can you share that view?

Comment: I solved the problem but a new one appeared https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57027321/im-doing-a-view-count-but-it-causes-an-error