# I'm doing a view count, but it causes an error

Tags: python, html, django

Name of error 'page_hits' is decorated with takes_context=True so it must have a first argument of 'context' 
I make the view counter. It is necessary that the function handles the entry of a person to the site and output it to a template.

Please give ready-made code for fix already read a lot about
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
Traceback:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\Desktop\RapterGame.com\RapterGames\news\views.py" in Detail
  195.     return render(request,'news/post_detail.html')

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
  15.             return engine.get_template(template_name)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in get_template
  34.             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in get_template
  143.         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py" in find_template
  125.                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loaders\base.py" in get_template
  30.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in __init__
  156.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in compile_nodelist
  194.             return parser.parse()

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in parse
  478.                     raise self.error(token, e)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in parse
  476.                     compiled_result = compile_func(self, token)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in compile_func
  121.                     kwonly, kwonly_defaults, takes_context, function_name,

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\library.py" in parse_bits
  250.                 "have a first argument of 'context'" % name)

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /Detail/
Exception Value: 'page_hits' is decorated with takes_context=True so it must have a first argument of 'context'
```

views.py

```
from django.template.loader_tags import register
from news.models import PageHit
from django import template

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(ctx, page_url=None):
    counter = (PageHit.objects
                      .filter(url=(ctx['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url))
                      .first())
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first name should be `context`, not `ctx`, as is specified in the [documentation of **`simple_tag`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag):

> If your template tag needs to access the current context, you can use
>   the **`takes_context`** argument when registering your tag:
>
> (...)
>
> Note that the **first argument must be called `context`**.

So you need to rewrite it to:

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(context, page_url=None):
    counter = PageHit.objects.filter(
        url=context['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url
    ).first()
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) (at the first mention of takes_context) "Note that the first argument must be called context."
Change to

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def page_hits(context, page_url=None):
    counter = (PageHit.objects
                      .filter(url=(context['request'].path if page_url is None else page_url))
                      .first())
    return 0 if counter is None else counter.count
```